# JArray.IndexOf always returns -1

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a JArray named jaLabels as below:

```
[
  "01-Jun",
  "02-Jun",
  "03-Jun",
  "04-Jun"
]
```

I'm trying to search '01-Jun' using C# codes below:

```
string date = "01-Jun";
int index = jaLabels.IndexOf(date);
```

why it returns -1?

```
JArray jaLabels = new JArray();
jaLabels.Add("01-Jun");
jaLabels.Add("02-Jun");
jaLabels.Add("03-Jun");
jaLabels.Add("04-Jun");

string date = "01-Jun";
int index = jaLabels.IndexOf(date);

Console.WriteLine(index);
```

I have tried:

```
int index = jaLabels.IndexOf(jaLabels.First(a => a.ToString().Equals(date)));
```

*But it doesn't give me -1* if I find the unlisted value (ie. "03-Mar")
But it thrown me an exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element.

Comment: Please post a [mre]

Comment: If it's returning `-1`, it's not finding the item. It's impossible to tell you why with a couple of lines of code that are totally out of context. Please provide a [mre] that can be copied and pasted into an IDE, and then run to reproduce the issue, as is required by the [help/on-topic] guidelines when asking for debugging help.

Comment: That's not actually valid JSON

Comment: Is `IndexOf` looking for a `string` or a `JToken`?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama It looks for a `JToken`, but there is an implicit conversion from `string` to `JToken`

Comment: Answer: Because `JArray.IndexOf` compares the reference - [source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JArray.cs#L278)

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, it looks for a string, did I do wrong?

Comment: @Don2 No, it does not look for a string, but there is an **implicit** conversion to `JToken`. `JToken token = "01-Jan";` is valid because of this implicit conversion that let you assing a `string` to a `JToken` variable.

Comment: @Don2 Here a [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p7XeWY) how to achieve this